# Simplification of $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \prod_{k=1}^{t} \left(\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{1}{(x^{a_k})^m}\right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \prod_{k=1}^{t} \left(\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{1}{(x^{a_k})^m}\right)$$

For $t=1$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \left(\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{1}{x^{a_1 m}}\right) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \left( \frac{\frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_1}}-1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{ \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1\right)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \left( \frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_1}}-1\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{(1-x^q)(1-x^{q-a_1})}
\end{align*}

For $t=2$:
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom=} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \left(\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{1}{x^{a_1 m}}\right) \left(\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{1}{x^{a_2 m}}\right )\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \left( \frac{\frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_1}}-1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1}\right)\left( \frac{\frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_2}}-1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{ \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1\right) \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1\right)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \left( \frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_1}}-1\right)\left( \frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_2}}-1\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{ \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1\right) \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1\right)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{x^{n(q-a_1-a_2)} }{x^{a_1+a_2}}- \frac{x^{n(q-a_1)} }{x^{a_1}} - \frac{x^{n(q-a_2)} }{x^{a_2}} + x^{q n}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{ \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1\right) \left(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1\right)} \left ( \frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2}-x^q} + \frac{1}{x^{a_1}-x^q} + \frac{1}{x^{a_2}-x^q} + \frac{1}{1-x^q}\right)\\
&= \frac{1-x^{2q-a_1-a_2}}{(1-x^q)(1-x^{q-a_1})(1-x^{q-a_2})(1-x^{q-a_1-a_2})}
\end{align*}

However, for $t=3$ the solution becomes unwieldy. Mathematica gives $\dfrac{P}{Q}$, where:
\begin{gather*}
P = x^{a_1+a_2+a_3} \left(-x^{4 q} \left(x^{a_1+a_2+2 a_3}+x^{a_3} \left(x^{a_1+2 a_2}+\left(x^{a_1}+3\right)\
x^{a_1+a_2}+x^{a_1}+x^{a_2}\right)+x^{a_1+a_2}\right)-\left(x^{a_1+a_2+2 a_3}+x^{a_3} \left(x^{a_1+2 a_2}+\left(x^{a_1}+3\right)
x^{a_1+a_2}+x^{a_1}+x^{a_2}\right)+x^{a_1+a_2}\right) x^{a_1+a_2+a_3+2 q}+2 \left(x^{a_1}+1\right) \left(x^{a_2}+1\right) \left(x^{a_3}+1\right) x^{a_1+a_2+a_3+3 q}+x^{3 (a_1+a_2+a_3)}+x^{6 q}\right)\\
Q = \left(x^q-1\right) \left(x^q-x^{a_1}\right) \left(x^q-x^{a_2}\right) \left(x^{a_3}-x^q\right) \left(x^q-x^{a_1+a_2}\right) \left(x^{a_1+a_3}-x^q\right) \left(x^{a_2+a_3}-x^q\right) \left(x^{a_1+a_2+a_3}-x^q\right)
\end{gather*}

So my two questions are as follows:

**Can the resulting sum always be put into a product of $(1-\sum_{m=0}x^{q-p_m})$ where $p_m$ is a combination of $a_t$ ?**

and

**Is there a convenient form (i.e. less messy) of the solutions for all $t$?**

Thanks.

Edit: Just realized I messed up the subscript of $a_k$ in the title. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\begin{align}&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \prod_{k=1}^{t} \left(\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{1}{(x^{a_k})^m}\right)
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \prod_{k=1}^{t} \frac{\frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_k}}-1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}
\\\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \prod_{k=1}^{t}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_k}}-1\bigg)\tag1\end{align}$$

Here, letting $y:=x^{-n-1}$, we have
$$\begin{align}&\prod_{k=1}^{t}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{(n+1)a_k}}-1\bigg)
\\\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{t}(y^{a_k}-1)
\\\\&=(y^{a_1}-1)(y^{a_2}-1)\cdots (y^{a_t}-1)
\\\\&=\sum_{m=0}^t(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom tm}y^{\sigma_{t-m}(j)}\end{align}$$
where $\sigma_n$ represents the sum of $n$ $a_j$s out of $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_t$.

So, we have
$$\begin{align}(1)&=\prod_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q} \sum_{m=0}^t(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom tm}y^{\sigma_{t-m}(j)}
\\\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{m=0}^t(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom tm}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n q}(x^{-n-1})^{\sigma_{t-m}(j)}
\\\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{m=0}^t(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom tm}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n(q-\sigma_{t-m}(j))-\sigma_{t-m}(j)}
\\\\&=\color{red}{\prod_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{m=0}^t(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom tm}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{t-m}(j)}-x^{q}}}\end{align}$$

under the condition that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}x^{(N+1)(q-\sigma_{t-m}(j))-\sigma_{t-m}(j)}=0$.

---

**Example 1** : For $t=3$, the sum can be written as
$$\prod_{k=1}^{3}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{m=0}^3(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom 3m}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{3-m}(j)}-x^{q}}\tag2$$

Since we can write
$$\begin{align}\sigma_{3}(1)&=a_1+a_2+a_3
\\\sigma_2(1)&=a_1+a_2
\\\sigma_2(2)&=a_2+a_3
\\\sigma_2(3)&=a_3+a_1
\\\sigma_1(1)&=a_1
\\\sigma_1(2)&=a_2
\\\sigma_1(3)&=a_3
\\\sigma_0(1)&=0\end{align}$$
we see that $(2)$ is equal to
$$\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_3}}-1)}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{3}(j)}-x^{q}}-\sum_{j=1}^{3}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{2}(j)}-x^{q}}+\sum_{j=1}^{3}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{1}(j)}-x^{q}}-\sum_{j=1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{0}(j)}-x^{q}}\bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_3}}-1)}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2+a_3}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_2+a_3}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_3+a_1}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_1}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_2}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_3}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{q}}\bigg)$$

---

**Example 2** : For $t=4$, the sum can be written as
$$\prod_{k=1}^{4}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{a_k}}-1}\sum_{m=0}^4(-1)^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\binom 4m}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{4-m}(j)}-x^{q}}\tag3$$

Since we can write
$$\begin{align}\sigma_{4}(1)&=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4
\\\sigma_3(1)&=a_1+a_2+a_3
\\\sigma_3(2)&=a_1+a_2+a_4
\\\sigma_3(3)&=a_1+a_3+a_4
\\\sigma_3(4)&=a_2+a_3+a_4
\\\sigma_2(1)&=a_1+a_2
\\\sigma_2(2)&=a_1+a_3
\\\sigma_2(3)&=a_1+a_4
\\\sigma_2(4)&=a_2+a_3
\\\sigma_2(5)&=a_2+a_4
\\\sigma_2(6)&=a_3+a_4
\\\sigma_1(1)&=a_1
\\\sigma_1(2)&=a_2
\\\sigma_1(3)&=a_3
\\\sigma_1(4)&=a_4
\\\sigma_0(1)&=0\end{align}$$
we see that $(3)$ is equal to
$$\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_3}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_4}}-1)}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{4}(j)}-x^{q}}-\sum_{j=1}^{4}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{3}(j)}-x^{q}}+\sum_{j=1}^{6}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{2}(j)}-x^{q}}-\sum_{j=1}^{4}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{1}(j)}-x^{q}}+\sum_{j=1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\sigma_{0}(j)}-x^{q}}\bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x^{a_1}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_2}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_3}}-1)(\frac{1}{x^{a_4}}-1)}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2+a_3}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2+a_4}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_3+a_4}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_2+a_3+a_4}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_2}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_3}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_1+a_4}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_2+a_3}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_2+a_4}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{x^{a_3+a_4}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_1}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_2}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_3}-x^{q}}-\frac{1}{x^{a_4}-x^{q}}+\frac{1}{1-x^{q}}\bigg)$$

Comment: That simplifies the sum but I was hoping that the simplification would be in product form as I displayed. That's my fault for not being specific enough. Thank you though. +1

Comment: It is also interesting that you used $\sigma$ when the motivation for this question comes from the fact that when you take the initial sum and multiply it over the primes you get $$ \prod_i^{\infty} f(1/p_i) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^t \sigma_{a_k}(n)}{n^q}$$ Hence why the product form solution is more interesting as it directly yields a closed form e.g. $\zeta(s) \zeta(s-a_1)$ etc. Where $\sigma$ in this case is the Divisor Function